# address calculation for variables inside structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct

This is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct test
{
  unsigned int x;
  long int y: 32;
  unsigned int z;
};

int main()
{
  struct test t;
  unsigned int *ptr1 = &t.x;
  unsigned int *ptr2 = &t.z;
  printf("ptr1 address is %p\n", ptr1);
  printf("ptr2 address is %p\n", ptr2);
  printf("size: %d", ptr2 - ptr1);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
ptr1 address is 0028FEDC
ptr2 address is 0028FEE4
size: 2
```

I think I am missing a point here in my understanding of the output. I was expecting the output to be 4. Since, long int occupies 4 bytes on my machine. And I am getting the difference between the address of x and z. However, not the real output, not the output I obtained by subtracting the address of x and z manually makes any sense. If you see above, 28FEE4-28FEDC = 8 according to my calculation, but output is 2. Can anyone tell me where I have got my calculations wrong?

Comment: If you want to use a 32-bit signed integer inside your structure, why use bitfields instead of e.g. `int32_t`?

Comment: You need to scale the difference of pointers by the size of the type pointed to in order to get the number of bytes: `ptr2-ptr1` = 2, multiply by `sizeof(unsigned int)`, which is evidently 4 on your system, to get 8 bytes.

Comment: Technically your subtraction of the two pointers is *undefined behavior*, since they don't both point to the "object".

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: It is just an exercise. Yes, you are right, I can use int32_t, but it was originally a much lower value to demonstrate that we would use whatever the size of long int is even if we are using few bits of it.

Comment: Bit fields of types other than `_Bool`, `int`, `unsigned` or `signed` are implementation-defined and may not even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To explain the behavior, you could look at your structure like this:

```
+---+---+---+
| x | y | z |
+---+---+---+
^       ^
|       |
&t.x    &t.z
```

The difference between `&t.x` and `&t.z` is *two* elements, first one from `&t.x` to `&t.y`, and then one from `&t.y` to `&t.z`.

It should be noted that this works *only* because all three types are the same size and the compiler haven't added any padding inside the structure.

Comment: Seems like I over thought on this because of the addresses value and forgot to scale it by the pointer type. Thanks!

Comment: And thank you for the note about padding. I forgot to even consider that as well.